# How to click a button on a site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, steam

To be specific, (although I am also interested in a general solution, if anyone would care to explain) I am trying to "click" Steam's 'Not Interested' button.

I have the urls of the pages I want to do this on in a Python script, alternatively I can write them in a file somewhere.

As much as I (think I) know about that button, it has no ID, and the relevant bit of code that is executed is:

```
$J.post('http://store.steampowered.com/recommended/ignorerecommendation/', {
  sessionid: g_sessionID,
  appid: store_appid
})
```

I am mostly unfamiliar with Javascript, but copying the headers and parameters, I managed to successfully send that post request (in Python instead), which worked. The problem with that is that it seems it requires the following cookies: steamRememberLogin, steamLogin, sessionid. I am rather sure those won't forever stay the same, and so my script would soon break.

I am unsure what to do from here on. I could imagine somehow automatically getting those cookies from somewhere, but where and how? Alternatively if something could actually send a click event from the button, I think that might be possible in Javascript?
And if this bit's important, then it doesn't need to operate in the background. As long as it can be scheduled, it's fine if it needs to actually open up that webpage in my browser.

Comment: Look into using selenium for browser automation: http://www.seleniumhq.org/  There's a python package available as well

Comment: Did you answer the question by yourself? Please post your answer because it's relevant to me too. =)